# Xcode compilers and OpenMP

Tags: xcode, llvm, openmp

Does anyone know what the reasoning is as to why the Apple compilers do not have OpenMP support (even though the official LLVM compilers have it)?  Is there another mechanism Apple "thinks" we should be using for shared memory parallel processing?

Answer (score 0):

You should try GDC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch ) for concurrency.
As of OpenMP, likely the lack of demand and the fact that it takes time to qualify new features.